# OAuth 2.0 for Google API requests in PHP Webhook

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I'm faced with a difficult scenario regarding OAuth 2 authentication and Google's Calendar API.

I am attempting to write a PHP script which processes my personal calendar data after being triggered by a POST call from an external source. However, I am having trouble granting the script access to my account. Since the script runs entirely in the background, there is never an opportunity for me to enter the authorization code which is required for PHP command line tools making Google API requests.

I have looked into Service Accounts, which grant access to personal data without individual approval, but unfortunately this is only available to G Suite users, which I am not.

I have also attempted to run my script manually, enter the code to authenticate, then run it from my external source. This doesn't work either, because the authorization codes are apparently only good for the same mode of access where it was entered, and the response to the external source still shows as asking for the code.

Lastly, please note that responding with the authorization code from the external source is not an option. Which I can activate the trigger, I cannot change how it works or the data it passes.

**TL;DR:** How do I grant a PHP script (which runs only in the background) access to my personal Google Calendar data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Articulating this question actually helped me better formulate my Google searches, and I found the answer!
I'll leave this question/answer here so somebody can hopefully benefit from it -

Turns out that the Service Account is the way to go, but instead of trying to access your account's data via the service account, you need to share the calendars in question with the generated service account email address. Essentially, this makes the service account a "co-owner" of the calendar. Then, you simply make the request to the service account's own information.

Hope this helps!